# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics.ktx

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics-android

Admittedly, I have very minimal programming experience and this is my first time using Android Studio so bear with me. I am looking to determine what's causing my Samsung J3 Prime to crash and Firebase Crashlytics seemed like a good route to take.

I've been following the guide [found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android) and am on Step 3, adhering to the 'Kotlin+KTX' instructions (that's just what I happened to choose for the project), but when attempting to sync the build I'm getting error

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics.ktx: Affected Modules: app

yet when I remove the .ktx suffix as per the Java instructions it syncs successfully -- why is that? Am I missing or misreading something?

Any help or guidance is appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: You should add `-ktx` instead of `.ktx`

Comment: Ah yes -- thanks, I figured it was likely something simple like that. I'm still confused as to why it configured without a problem without the '-ktx' suffix though; I would've assumed it would throw an error for that?